# Line Spacing Between Aligned Equations

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, line-spacing, mathspec

[image]

I've been typing this equations but these equations does not get enough line spacing spacing. I get space sufficient if I did type them separately but I want them aligned too.

following is the code:

```
\begin{align*}
\chi^2 & = \frac{\sigma_{s}^{2}}{\sigma_{p}^{2}} (n-1)\\
& = \frac{31.11}{20} (10-1) \\
& = 13.999
\end{align*}
```

---

preamble if needed to understand what Im doing wrong

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=1.5cm, outer=1.5cm, top=1.0cm,
bottom=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathpazo}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Off-topic: Don't load both `enumerate` and `enumitem`; choose one or the other, *but not both*. I'd recommend using `enumitem`... And there's no point in loading `mathpazo` if you're going to clobber it later by loading `mathptmx`.

Answer (score 7):

When working with `align*` and the multi-row math environments of the `amsmath` package, a useful paramater to know about is `\jot`: it governs the default amount of whitespace padding that's inserted between the rows. The default value of `\jot` is 3pt; you may want to increase its value to 6pt, especially as you're using a fairly large value for the document's basic font size. (The default value of `\jot` is *not* increased automatically if a document font size larger than 10pt is used.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}

% What's needed to get the sample document to compile:
\usepackage{amsmath,mathptmx}

\begin{document}

\begingroup % Localize scope of the next instruction:
\addtolength\jot{3pt} % default value: 3pt
\begin{align*}
\chi^2 &= \frac{\sigma_{s}^{2}}{\sigma_{p}^{2}} (n-1)\\
       &= \frac{31.11}{20} (10-1) \\
       &= 13.9995 \,.
\end{align*}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```